# фильтр Габора, openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

подскажите как сделать сегментацию изображения, то есть применять фильтр к выделенной области изображения
Код программы:

```
 #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


cv::Mat mkKernel(int ks, double sig, double th, double lm, double ps)
{
    int hks = (ks - 1) / 2;
    double theta = th * CV_PI / 180;
    double psi = ps * CV_PI / 180;
    double del = 2.0 / (ks - 1);
    double lmbd = lm;
    double sigma = sig / ks;
    double x_theta;
    double y_theta;
    cv::Mat kernel(ks, ks, CV_32F);
    // задали область определения
    for (int y = -hks; y <= hks; y++)
    {
        for (int x = -hks; x <= hks; x++)
        {
            // поворот
            x_theta = x * del * cos(theta) + y * del * sin(theta);
            y_theta = -x * del * sin(theta) + y * del * cos(theta);
            // ядро
            kernel.at<float>(hks + y, hks + x) = (float)exp(-0.5 * (pow(x_theta, 2) + pow(y_theta, 2)) / pow(sigma, 2)) * cos(2 * CV_PI * x_theta / lmbd + psi);
        }
    }
    return kernel;
}

int kernel_size = 21;
int pos_sigma = 3;
int pos_lm = 50;
int pos_th = 0;
int pos_psi = 90;
Mat src_f;
Mat dest;

class Timer
{
private:
    // Псевдонимы типов используются для удобного доступа к вложенным типам
    using clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using second_t = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1> >;

    std::chrono::time_point<clock_t> m_beg;

public:
    Timer() : m_beg(clock_t::now())
    {
    }

    void reset()
    {
        m_beg = clock_t::now();
    }

    double elapsed() const
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<second_t>(clock_t::now() - m_beg).count();
    }
};
void Process(int, void*)
{
    double sig = pos_sigma;
    double lm = 0.5 + pos_lm / 100.0;
    double th = pos_th;
    double ps = pos_psi;
    Mat kernel = mkKernel(kernel_size, sig, th, lm, ps);
    filter2D(src_f, dest, CV_32F, kernel);
    imshow("Process window", dest);
    Mat Lkernel(kernel_size * 30, kernel_size * 30, CV_32F);
    resize(kernel, Lkernel, Lkernel.size());
    Lkernel /= 2.;
    Lkernel += 0.5;
    imshow("Kernel", Lkernel);
    Mat mag;
    pow(dest, 2.0, mag);
    imshow("Mag", mag);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    Timer t;
    Mat image = imread("1.jpg", 1);
    imshow("Src", image);
    Mat src;
    if (!kernel_size % 2)
    {
        kernel_size += 1;
    }
    cvtColor(image, src, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    src.convertTo(src_f, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255, 0);
    namedWindow("Process window", 1);
    createTrackbar("Sigma", "Process window", &pos_sigma, kernel_size, Process);
    createTrackbar("Lambda", "Process window", &pos_lm, 100, Process);
    createTrackbar("Theta", "Process window", &pos_th, 180, Process);
    createTrackbar("Psi", "Process window", &pos_psi, 360, Process);
    Process(0, 0);
    std::cout << t.elapsed() << '\n';
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не понял вопрос: вам нужно применить фильтр к заранее известной части изображения, или найти какую-то заранее неизвестную часть изображения?

Comment: Допустим есть изображение и нужно применить фильтр к части этого изображения, я пытался сделать прямоугольную область выделения, но у меня получался чёрный прямоугольник

Comment: эта "часть изображения" заранее известна?

Comment: да, она заранее известна

Comment: В таком случае просто используйте `operator()` с прямоугольником описывающим эту часть изображения - на выходе получите новую матрицу (без копирования) с которой можете работать а с отдельным изображением

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: operator() - это функция opencv?

Comment: а вы точно знаете с++?

Comment: нет, я не утверждал, что знаю с++, но мне нужно с этим разобраться)

Comment: странный у вас подход, не слышали пословицу: не зная броду не лезь в воду? `operator()` это зарезервированное имя метода, которое преобразует объект класса в функтор